# How Would I Retrieve All Git Commit SHA-1 Hashes Deployed to AppEngine Using the CLI?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The "Versions" page in the AppEngine section of the GCP console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) displays a table containing all of the `git` `commit` SHA-1 hashes that have been deployed for a given AppEngine Service.

How would I display this list using the `gcloud` CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to generate the table you're looking for using the `app` group within the `gcloud` CLI.

Here is an example table with some formatting and asc. sorting:

```sh
gcloud app versions list \
--format="table[box](last_deployed_time.datetime:label=DEPLOYED, version.id:label=GIT_COMMIT_HASH)" \
--service=$GAE_SERVICE_NAME \
--sort-by=DEPLOYED

#=>

┌───────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          DEPLOYED         │             GIT_COMMIT_HASH              │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 1970-01-01 00:00:00-00:00 │ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx │
│           . . .           │                  . . .                   │
│           . . .           │                  . . .                   │
│           . . .           │                  . . .                   │
│ 1970-01-01 00:00:01-00:00 │ yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```